# Where is the code of chain reorganization in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, chain-reorganization

I'm trying to understand how Bitcoin Core works in-depth. Can someone tell me where is the code executed during a blockchain reorganization in Bitcoin Core?

Any explanation would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where in Bitcoin Core does it do X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87450/where-in-bitcoin-core-does-it-do-x)

Comment: When you say reorganization, do you mean a spontaneous fork in the blockchain? or are you referring to the suggestion of Binance recently after their hack, to “reorganize” and rollback the blockchain, and you are wondereing if there is code in place to do the reorg of the blockchain? (spoiler alert: there isn’t any).

Comment: @bitcoinero I mean spontaneous fork. How the best chain is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block tree is stored on-disk. During startup, is read into memory. When read, `BlockManager::m_block_index` field is filled with data - CBlockIndexes. Every CBlockIndex contains memory-only field `arith_uint256 nChainWork`, which is a total amount of work in the chain up to (and including) current block.

Best chain is selected as maximum among all `nChainWork` of all tips and saved to `CChainState::m_chain` - currently active chain.