# Study bitcoin core source code

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have read a lot of documentation and books where they explain the general functioning of Bitcoin and I think that the time has come to study the source code of Bitcoin core.

I have knowledge of c++ and python but due to the large size of the project and the number of files, I don't know where it would be correct to start.

Could someone help me on how to properly perform that task?

Comment: Well, which part of its functionality are you most interested in?

Comment: I would like to start with the creation and validation of transactions. I am also interested in how the wallet works.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/98433/103136

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87450/where-in-bitcoin-core-does-it-do-x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where in Bitcoin Core does it do X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87450/where-in-bitcoin-core-does-it-do-x)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advice. They will be very useful to me.